# MikTeX Console stop working

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9

Two weeks ago i observe that in recent days (after last Windows upgrade at January 1st ?) the MikTeX Console stop works. Clicking on its icon show some activities that it (try to) start, but its window doesn't appear on screen.

Then i try to reinstall MikTeX, but after selecting it in control panel and clicking on button "uninstall" nothing happen.

I like to update my MikTeX installation as well to add new path for searching in new sub directories which i create recently  for some my new private style packages.

Do anyone experience something similar? Any suggestion what to do?

I use 64.bit MikTeX an for OS Window 10 with recent updates from 1.1.2019 (KB4483234, KB4477137).

**Edit:**
Thank you very much to all who write comments. They help me in searching for solution of the my problem. It is now solved. In this I use brute force:

- install new disk (since capacity of the old one became to small) in my laptop
- define new users names with only 7-bit ASCII characters (but last year it works with ščž ... too)
- download recent MikTeX 64-bit basic installer and with it install MikTeX for private use
- test Console: it works!
- test uninstall: it works!
- reinstall MikTeX: it works now!

Comment: Add an issue to the MiKTeX issue tracker.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, where is MikTeX issue tracker? I sent a letter to `miktex-users@lists.sourceforge.net`, but there was not any response (at least i didn't receive any answer). Tomorrow I have a plan to replace exist SSD with  bigger new with fresh installation of OS, but i afraid to install MikTeX too since if the Console will not work in i will not be able to  uninstall it, than i will have old problems ...

Comment: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thank you for the link. Unfortunately, all my attempts to sign up for `githup` were unsuccessful. Can you do this instead of me?

Comment: That wouldn't work: I know nothing about your PC and can't give the relevant infos.

Comment: The 10/2018 release caused console to start using `/bin/ ` instead of `\bin\ `.  I believe Windows 10 can actually handle such pathnames, but Windows 7 cannot.  In either case, changing the pathname means that console cannot find the executables.

Comment: Oh, try deleting the entire miktex folder.  That is generally sufficient (and necessary) to reinstall.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, thank you very much for info. I try this: delete MikTeX folder and install MikTeX again.  But this didn't help. Console is not possible to lunch nor uninstall MikTex. It seems that recent MikTeX doesn't have file for uninstalling or the path to it is corrupt.

Comment: I had to reinstall using the 1/2019 version, and it works fine on Windows 7.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, tomorrow, when i will get new disk, I will try to make fresh installation od OS (W10) as well as recent MikTeX. Since I'm now without MIkTeX, i cant check the paths in its installation.  I will do this tomorrow.

Comment: I recommend you may find the portable version easier to manage for a single user. There are some that say it is a security risk to install on C:\mytexapp or similar since its outside the user control boundary. However if you are suspicious/careful what you download and have suitable anti trojan software in place it is then easy to delete if you think to replace it. Back to current version You should be able to navigate to bin directory in which there was/still is? miktexsetup.exe and in that folder run a command as admin **in that folder, from the command line run> miktexsetup factoryreset**

Comment: Forgot to add in the same way you can also try **miktexsetup uninstall**

Comment: Glad it is solved, and should be easier to refresh if necessary. You may transfer your findings to your own answer and accept it to avoid it appearing on the unanswered list.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments